# Getting error while masking the NetCDF file for a particular region in R?

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, rgdal, netcdf4

I have the following script that i wrote to clip the `netCDF` file based on my `Shapefile`. the `NetCDF` file contains soil information. when i am `masking` the `NetCDF` file using my `shapefile`, i am getting error. Any suggestions on how to tackle the problem would be appreciated. my `netCDF` file is heavy which is why i didn't attach it here so am sharing the link to the `NetCDF` file and `Shapefile` [GoogleDriveLink](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xfJ6SVVWX8l8eI6lFC9FeEHeJJE2fr-/view?usp=sharing).

```
library(ncdf4)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

NC_File <- "ADD_PROP1_NCRB.nc"
print(nc_open(NC_File))
```

Description of the NetCDF file

```
1 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        byte ADD_PROP[lon,lat]   
            long_name: additional property 
            _FillValue: -100
            missing_value: -100

     2 dimensions:
        lon  Size:3377
            standard_name: longitude
            long_name: longitude
            units: degrees_east
            axis: X
        lat  Size:1725
            standard_name: latitude
            long_name: latitude
            units: degrees_north
            axis: Y
```

Raster conversion using brick function

```
b <- brick(NC_File)
b
> b 
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 1725, 3377, 5825325, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.00833333, 0.00833333  (x, y)
extent     : -117.6917, -89.55003, 45.31663, 59.69162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : G:/Nelson_MIP/ForcingFilesFromOneDrive/Soil/GSDE_NCRB/ADD_PROP1_NCRB.nc 
names      : layer 
varname    : ADD_PROP
```

Reading my shapefile for masking NetCDF

```
SHP <- readOGR("G:/Nelson_MIP/WatershedFile/ForSoilNetCDFprocessing.shp")
SHP
> SHP
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : -103.7103, -101.7075, 50.83711, 52.35122  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs 
variables   : 1
names       : Strahler_O 
value       :          5
```

match projection of the shapefile to that of NetCDF file

```
SHP <- spTransform(SHP, crs(NC_File))
```

Clip NetCDF file using my shapefile

```
Masking <- mask(b, SHP)
> Masking <- mask(b, SHP)
Error in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset,  : 
  Error: variable has 2 dims, but start has 3 entries.  They must match!
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could make the file available in some way (dropbox, google drive)

Comment: Thanks@RobertHijmans - I just provided a link to the `NetCDF` and `Shapefile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that I have fixed in the [development version](https://github.com/rspatial/raster) of `raster`.
With the current version, you can work around it by using `raster` rather than `brick` as this is a one layer dataset

```
library(raster)
b <- raster("ADD_PROP1_NCRB.nc")
s <- shapefile("ForSoilNetCDFprocessing.shp")
s <- spTransform(s, crs(b))
m <- mask(b, s)
```